# Hide particular element from a list in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm generating down-caret and right-caret font awesome icons repeatedly in a component template using `*ngFor` within `<tr>`s. I'm hiding one and showing the other based on a `Boolean` value I set in the associated class. But when I change the `Boolean` value, it hides all the other icons as well. I just want to hide the one I click on instead of the others. Is there a way of doing this within the template itself by setting a property in the template and changing it in the class instead of getting both the elements and then hiding them in the class?

Code:

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of arr">
        <td id="{{obj.Parent}}" class='level{{obj.Level}}'>                
        <i *ngIf="showCollapse" (click)="collapseClicked($event)" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <I *ngIf="showExpand" (click)="expandClicked($event)" class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{obj.ATA}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.Description}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.MSI}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell Angular which item should be expanded or collapsed. A single flag for your component can not be assigned with a single item.

Try instead:

```
<tr *ngFor="let obj of arr">
        <td id="{{obj.Parent}}" class='level{{obj.Level}}'>                
        <i *ngIf="showCollapse === obj" (click)="collapseClicked(obj)" class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <I *ngIf="showExpand === obj" (click)="expandClicked(obj)" class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        {{obj.ATA}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.Description}}</td>
        <td>{{obj.MSI}}</td>
</tr>
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  arr = [{Parent: 'xxx', Level: 'yyy'}, {Parent: 'aaa', Level: 'bbb'},];
  showCollapse:any;
  showExpand:any;
  constructor() {
    this.showCollapse = this.arr[1];
    this.showExpand = this.arr[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But won't both the icons show in this case since both evaluate to true here? I'm working on an expand / collapse sort of functionality where if I click on the collapse icon, the expand icon should show, hide the collapse icon and hide some tr's and vice versa.

Comment: I wasn't able to get from your question what you exactly want to do. I just tried to point out an approach that shows how you can switch a single item.

Comment: Oh OK. I got how to assign to an item for collapse / expand but my question is how do I hide that particular expand/collapse icon when clicked instead of hiding all the other icons?

Comment: I see. I updated my answer. `(click)="collapseClicked(obj)"` (`obj` instead of `$event`) but I don't know what exactly should happen. You need to update `this.showCollapse` and/or `this.showExpand` in `collapseClicked() { ... }` and/or `expandClicked() { ... }` to reflect the item you want to have collapsed or exanded or set to `null` for none.